# Can't get same answer in c and excel with same function

Tags: c, excel

I use c to calculate the following function,but can't get correct answer(in excel using function "INT" it is correct answer,when in c,I use"floor" to replace.).

function:

[image]

my code in c:

```
int ans;
ans = 1721013.5+367*Y-floor((7/4)*(Y+floor((M+9)/12)))+
        D+h/24+floor(275*M/9);
```

and I get wrong answer 2459700 when Y=2018,M=3,D=9,h=9

Correct answer:2458187

Comment: `7/4` is an integer calculation where the result will be `1` rather than `1.75`.  You have some other calculations of this nature.  You probably want to operate on `double`s, so you would instead do something like `7.0/4.0`

Comment: And `h / 24` will be 0; use `h / 24.0`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to replace all constant *int* by *double* is enough :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int Y=2018,M=3,D=9,h=9; /* can be double of course */
  int ans = ceil(1721013.5+367.0*Y-floor((7.0/4.0)*(Y+floor((M+9.0)/12.0)))+
    D+h/24.0+floor(275.0*M/9.0));

  printf("%d\n", ans);
}
```

I needed to use *ceil* to print 2458187 else I get 2458186

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra f.c -lm
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2458187
```

---

Additional remark, out of the initial problem, because the expression can be reduced by a constant (nothing is variable) the computation can be done at compile time rather than at execution time :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -O3 f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f.s 
    .arch armv6
    ...
main:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    push    {r4, lr}
    ldr r1, .L3
    ldr r0, .L3+4
    bl  printf
    mov r0, #0
    pop {r4, pc}
.L4:
    .align  2
.L3:
    .word   2458187
    ...
```

here the value was computed at compile time : `.word    2458187`